# How to access users calendar list and events from google api using access token and refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I already have obtained users access token from google api using oAuth2. Now i want to use this token to get user events/calendars. I have tried following code but it is not working.

Can anyone here help me with this please.
Thanks

```
    var urlBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    urlBuilder.Append("https://");
    urlBuilder.Append("www.googleapis.com");
    urlBuilder.Append("/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
    urlBuilder.Append("?minAccessRole=reader");

    var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(urlBuilder.ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;

    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] string.Format("Bearer {0}", data.access_token);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream eventResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader eventResponseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string eventsStr = eventResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution using `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3`, i am posting it here so may help someone else. Following is the code to get the events list when you have refresh token of a user:

First get new access token using the refresh token:

```
string postString = "client_id=yourclientid";
postString += "&client_secret=youclientsecret&refresh_token=userrefreshtoken";
postString += "&grant_type=refresh_token";
string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(postString);
Stream os = null;

    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    os = request.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


    GoogleToken token = new GoogleToken();

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    token = serializer.Deserialize<GoogleToken>(result);
```

Then use the toke and refresh token to create credentials.

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = yourclientid,
                    ClientSecret = yourclientsecret
                },
                Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
            });



            var credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, new TokenResponse
            {
                AccessToken = token.access_token,
                RefreshToken = userrefreshtoke
            });


            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "application name",
            });
            var list = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
            foreach (var c in list)
            {
                var events = service.Events.List(c.Id).Execute().Items.Where(i => i.Start.DateTime >= DateTime.Now).ToList();
                foreach (var e in events)
                {
                }
}
```

GoogleToken class:

```
 public class GoogleToken
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [.NET Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) provided by Google you'll be needing to download a *client_secret.json* which is part of the authentication process. Check the whole process in the link.

Here' a snippet for feching events in .NET:

```
// List events.
Events events = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
{
foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
{
string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
{
when = eventItem.Start.Date;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
}
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
}
Console.Read();
```

You can also read more of oAuth related guides in [.NET here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

For more info on retrieving Calendar lists and events, [read this guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My scenario is different. I want to get other users calendar events who authenticate through my google application. Offline access to user events.