# How to Sync Database with Google Calender

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I am using this code and it works and allows my app to get the `Calendar` List from the used google account.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(

new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "xxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxxx-xxxx",
},
            new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
            "support@xxx.com",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;



    // Create the service.
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "xxx",
    });

    CalendarListResource.ListRequest cal = service.CalendarList.List();
    cal.MaxResults = 10;

    var calresult = cal.Execute().Items;
```

My question is when i do this i than import all the Calender's And Events to my local database so after an hour i need to run a script to update the Database with the latest Calendar and Event info as they might have added new Events or deleted some same goes with Calender's.

Not sure where to look for any suggestion?

Comment: "My question"...but then the sentence which follows is not actually a question. Are you asking how to run your script on a schedule? You can make a Windows Service, or trigger your program from a Windows Scheduled Task. But also...have you considered whether you actually need to sync between your DB and Google Calendar? Your DB will always be potentially a bit out of date. Why not just query the info direct from Google Calendar at the time when you actually need it? Then you always get the latest version, and you don't need to mess around with synchronisation processes.

Comment: @ADyson  Regarding the windows service and related i can do no issue in that. But my main question is how do i connect to someones calendar when running script i mean on the website they allowed the app and it got their info so a bit stuck where to look..

Comment: There are tutorials provided by google on their API documentation which show how to do it when the user has logged in via Oauth. Your code right now looks like maybe it's using a service account instead, to always connect to the same Google ID? I am thinking that because of the use of the client secret, although your code sample looks incomplete to me (admittedly I've only ever used the APIs via PHP so I could be wrong, but there you go).

Comment: @ADyson i have been looking around but did not found what i am looking for which is mentioned above.

Comment: @ADyson  you can connect to any gmail account and allow the app and it basically reads the Calendar List from that account.

Comment: well we are not really here to do your googling for you, but https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth, https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet, and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 should all help to get you started. Someone might have even posted a complete example using C# somewhere if you're lucky. P.S. Once you've authenticated to the API using the identity of the logged in user and got your access token, the rest of the process (retrieving calendars, events etc) is basically identical to when you use a service account

Comment: I still think you should consider whether a full sync is really the best solution. I don't know your requirements but do you really need to know _all_ of the user's events up front? Will you use all of them?

Comment: One thing to note as well - doing an automated resync once an hour will not work well with OAuth - the access tokens eventually expire (you can refresh them, but eventually you run out) and the user has to enter their credentials again. So basically you can only guarantee to have a successful sync when the user is present. That's another good reason why you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: @ADyson Wont need all the events can live with next 30 days  and prev 2 days.  But my main question is once again how do i read the Calendar of some one who has authorized me app on the website in script

Comment: Cause as you said "So basically you can only guarantee to have a successful sync when the user is present"

Comment: the same way you read it when you connect with a service account. I mentioned this already. The only difference is you need the user's access token instead of your service account details. So you cannot do this in some offline / external process, it needs to be part of your website really. Or at least you need to pass the access token to the external service quickly and run the sync before the token expires. I really think an on-demand approach might be more effective than trying to bulk download a whole bunch of events at regular intervals.

Comment: so if after an hour or maybe 5 hours i nee to run a script that will check Events and send a reminder to those which are less than a day. That is no possible from what i get in your comments?

Comment: yes, but as I mentioned above this is time-limited, the token will expire after a relatively short time. Maybe if you explain to me what your application will do with this calendar data, we can think of a better design.

Comment: Basically i want to send reminders so you have 10 events one of them is  5 hours away so i sent email to you telling you have appointment etc something like that.

Comment: that's all? Google calendar already provides such functionality. Maybe you should just use your access to their account to add reminder data to their Google events (if they don't have them already), and then let google do the rest.

Comment: google does not send SMS :) so i add that aswell etc..

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that adds a bit of extra functionality. Actually I just searched a bit more and found something. It appears that if you request a Refresh Token from the API for the user's account, you can store that and it will not expire unless the user revokes your application's access to their account explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839734/5947043 for example. So I think your automated service can store the refresh token and use that to get a new access token when it needs to sync the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others:

The answer is here:

[How to access users calendar list and events from google api using access token and refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490536/how-to-access-users-calendar-list-and-events-from-google-api-using-access-token)

Basically you save the token and later user it for that Calendar.